# Heroku cannot find private npmjs modules

Tags: heroku, configuration, module, npm, codeship

I'm new to Heroku and I've got an application that has private npmjs dependencies listed in its package.json file like this:

```
...
dependencies: {
    "@myscope/somemodule": "0.0.1", 
    ....
}
```

And I've got my .npmrc file setup like so:

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}
```

Where NPM_TOKEN has been set as a local environment variable and as a configuration variable in Heroku and on Codeship

The Heroku app fails to deploy both locally and on Codeship.

**Specifically, I get a 404 error code that says somemodule cannot be found in the registry.**

Further note, I can run a local instance of the Heroku app

I'm following this article:

http://blog.npmjs.org/post/118393368555/deploying-with-npm-private-modules

Am I missing a step?

Thanks!

Comment: It might be worth double checking the token on npmjs.com - I had this issue and it was because a token had vanished (either expired or removed by `$ npm logout`)

Comment: I keep hitting this lately, also have my NPM_TOKEN var configured correctly